# Is the discovered city of Dwarka related to Lord Krishna

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

Many Hindu [Blogs](http://mahabharata-research.com/about%20the%20epic/the%20lost%20city%20of%20dwarka.html) and [videos](https://youtu.be/BrBANMDDKV8) claim that the Dwarka which is discovered by National Institute of Oceanography scientist S.R Rao is related to Lord Krishna. Many people are giving [fake information](https://www.google.com/amp/s/m.timesofindia.com/times-fact-check/news/fact-check-these-photos-arent-proof-of-sri-krishnas-dwarka-in-gujarat/amp_articleshow/71385329.cms) on social media. But the dates given by Archeologist are parallel to that of the Mahabharata and Hindu scriptures. As per the survey of [National Institute of Oceanography](http://drs.nio.org/drs/handle/2264/3290) Dwarka sunk underwater around 3500 years ago (1500BC). The image is taken from the PDF of the survey given on their official site I quoted above.
[image]

Another research paper [Journal of Marine Archeology Vol 5-6 (1995-1996)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://mahabharata-resources.org/ola/J_Mar_Archaeol_5_6_61.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjkvO3mx_jnAhW1juYKHXEFCsIQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3HM6wMln89z93f9R0iafvA) page 64 gives the date of 1700-1600 BC.
[image]

Another report published in [Times of India](https://www.newindianexpress.com/lifestyle/spirituality/2018/aug/12/the-mythical-city-of-dwarka-1855600.html) says that Dwarka sunked 9000 years ago.

> The city was also extremely well planned: divided into six sectors which were in turn divided into residential, commercial areas. The city was home to beautiful large roads, gardens and artificial lakes. **It is said that it was submerged in the big flood 9,000 years ago.**

Now as per the [Mausal Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m16/m16001.htm) Dwarka sunked years after the Kurukshetra war and strating of kaliyug which should be around 3000bc or 5000 years ago. **can anyone give any scientific proof which could prove that the discovered city related to Lord Krishna?**